Troubleshooting PUT API Issues After Server Deployment
We have deployed our service on the server (IIS server), but the PUT API is returning a 405 (Method Not Allowed) error when we try to hit it. Rest all the APIs works. We have added code to the web.config file, but we are still facing the same issue. here is the code;
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
    <removename="WebDAVModule"/>
  </modules>
</system.webServer>

We have also double-checked our endpoint and confirmed that we are using the HTTP PUT method. What are we missing here?

What does "the PUT API is not working" mean exactly?

getting 405 (Method Not Allowed) error when we hit PUT api

iis and asp.net version?

The latest stable version of IIS as of my last update was IIS 10.0.20 with Windows Server 2022,  and Asp.Net used 8

So the PUT API works locally, but doesn't work when deployed? Is that correct?

Does this help at all?

Yes, right, It works locally

We did the same, but still got the same error.  Also, We have disable WebDevModule.

Thanks, everyone. The issue has been resolved. The problem was that we needed to restart the server after changing the WebDevModule.
